# Using ListView and Repeater together

Tags: asp.net, listview, c#-4.0, repeater

I would like to put Repeater inside a Repeater.  Since my list view has both ItemTemplate and AlternateItemTemplate, do I need to add two repeaters and bind both repeaters?

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvData" runat="server" onitemdatabound="lvData_ItemDataBound">
    <layouttemplate>
        <div style="border:dotted 1px gray;">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </layouttemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
        <div class="ListView">
            <h5><%# Eval("CourseCode") %> - <%# Eval("CourseName") %></h5> 
             <asp:Repeater ID="rptComments" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="No comments to display..." runat="server" Visible='<%#bool.Parse((rptComments.Items.Count==0).ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater> 
        </div>
    </itemtemplate>
    <alternatingitemtemplate>
        <div class="ListViewAlternate">
            <h5><%# Eval("CourseCode") %> - <%# Eval("CourseName") %></h5>        
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptComments2" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Comment") %></p>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpty" Text="No comments to display..." runat="server" Visible='<%#bool.Parse((rptComments.Items.Count==0).ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </alternatingitemtemplate>
    <emptydatatemplate>
    No records to display.
</emptydatatemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes.

Alternatively, do not use AlternatingItemTemplate, but instead, within ItemTemplate create markup that alternates based on your own logic. You basically only need to make that div/@class different.

If you can somehow retrieve the index/position of the item, from within the ItemTemplate markup, then you can use a simple division by 2 to determine if the item is odd or even.

`idx % 2 > 0` --> odd; else even

odd:

```
<div class="ListViewAlternate">
```

even

```
<div class="ListView">
```

Then, of course, you can have only one child-repeater there.